# Notepad++ Wildcard Find/Replace

Tags: regex, replace, find, notepad++

I'm using Notepad++ and need to update a file where there are various differences in earlier sections of the string of text and think Wildcards may help here. From the research I've done thus far, it isn't clear what syntax would be used for this.

Here's an example of the original string:

> "EEID","SUPLIFE","Voluntary Life Insurance","500000.00","500000.00",0,276,10.62.0,0,0,"20151112","","A","","","","",""

I'd like to find a way to add wildcards in the places noted below as WILDCARD:

> "EEID","SUPLIFE","Voluntary Life Insurance","WILDCARD","WILDCARD",WILDCARD,WILDCARD,WILDCARD,WILDCARD,WILDCARD,WILDCARD,"20151112","","A","","","","",""

The final output would then look like the following after the find/replace with wildcards to add VLIFE:

> "EEID","SUPLIFE","Voluntary Life Insurance","500000.00","500000.00",0,276,10.62.0,0,0,"20151112","","A","VLIFE","","","",""

Thanks,

Brandon

Comment: Why not just `"A",""` replace with `"A","VLIFE"`

Comment: Fair question. The reason is there are several other products other than the VLIFE product on the file that have "A"," " present so it would change all the others too.

Answer (score 0):

Tested in Notepad++ and appears to work:

```
("EEID","SUPLIFE","Voluntary Life Insurance",([^,]+,){8}"","A",)("")(.*)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

and replace pattern:

```
\1"VLIFE"\4
```

[Regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/rC7mF7/1)

Comment: Thanks Macro Man - I will test it shortly here!

Comment: So I wasn't able to get this working. It stated it was an invalid expression. I have the search mode set to regular expression along with the box checked for. matches new line. I did try it a few times with and without that toggled. It wasn't able to find the text in the first place so I didn't bother trying to replace it thereafter if it isn't able to locate the string first. Any thoughts?

Comment: Make sure the cursor is at the start of your text, it only looks at the text after the cursor. And make sure the "matches new line" box is NOT ticked.